# when I run this code I get the TypeError: Can you please guide me what steps do I take

Tags: python-3.x

. #Finds the unit with minimum speed. # If there are more than 1 units then the first occured # For an empty list the function returns None

```
def findSlowestUnit(units):
     slowestUnit = None;
     minSpeed = 0
     for currentUnit in units:
       if currentUnit['speed'] > minSpeed:
            slowestUnit = currentUnit
            minSpeed = currentUnit.speed
     return currentUnit
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I was trying to debug this code but I am not able to find where did go wrong

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample input, the output you're getting and the output you'd like to get for it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Answer (score 0):

```
def findSlowestUnit(units):
     slowestUnit = None;
     minSpeed = float('inf')
     for currentUnit in units:
       if currentUnit['speed'] < minSpeed:
            slowestUnit = currentUnit
            minSpeed = currentUnit['speed']
     return slowestUnit
```

Comment: this is the output I get     print(findSlowestUnit(200))
  File "C:/Users/bhavika/Desktop/shonal/shonal/Demo level 3 script and ppts/Python/games/Basic_game/debug_code.py", line 8, in findSlowestUnit
    for currentUnit in units:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a change in the solution, changed the line ```minSpeed = currentUnit.speed``` to ```minSpeed = currentUnit['speed']```